# Selenium - eCLIPSE - WebDriver Alert Handling - Query

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver

In eclipse i intend to automate below steps
(1) Open Google Chrome browser
(2) Enter https://www.flipkart.com/
(3) Maximize the window
(4) (after few seconds), the website shows a new pop-up window to login.
(5) just close the pop-window using the "X" icon at the top right corner.

have named the alert window as sharp in the code but

on the code Alert Sharp = Flip.switchTo().alert(); getting an warning information as "The Value of the local variable sharp is not used"

while executing, step 4 & 5 are not executed. have used Sharp.dismiss();also but still not failing.

have written the below code for the same. please clarify

```
package basic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;

public class FlipKart{

    public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\Selenium\\browser\\chromedriver.exe"); 

    WebDriver Flip = new ChromeDriver();
    Flip.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    Flip.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(5000); //FLIPKART CODE
    Alert Sharp = Flip.switchTo().alert();// pop -up window shown
```

// clicking X icon at the top right corner to close the window.

```
Flip.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button")).click(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button")).click();
```

Edit

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button"))).click();
```

Comment: Only xpath should do. Waiting for Alert will throw **TimeoutExcpetion** as there is no alert involved in page source.

Comment: @Mkay - yeah, you are correct. I am updating my answer. Thanks

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/butto‌​n")).click(); not working. selenium not recognizing the pop-up window. error message shows no web elements having the given xpath is exists

Comment: As you mentioned the website shows a new pop-up window to login, I checked it out and there is no as such window coming up. For that, you will have to induce some ExplicitWait. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Login division of Flipkart is a separate division and it is neither included in Alert nor in pop-up window / frame. So simply use xpath to locate element [X] and click that to close the login window.
Below simple statement worked for me.

**Remove**

```
Thread.sleep(5000); //FLIPKART CODE
    Alert Sharp = Flip.switchTo().alert();
```

**Preserve**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/button")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/button")).click(); not working. selenium not recognizing the pop-up window. error message shows no web elements having the given xpath is exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you mentioned `the website shows a new pop-up window to login. just close the pop-window using the "X" icon at the top right corner` if you try to locate the element through `Development Tools` the popup stems out from the `HTML DOM`. Hence, we won't be able to handle this popup through `Alert` Class as you tried `Alert Sharp = Flip.switchTo().alert();`. Instead we will close the popup through the `WebDriver` as follows:

> It is worth to mention the popup appears after some time so we should induce some `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` for the popup to appear.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Q45129845_Flipkart_Login_Close 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        WebDriver Flip = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Flip.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Flip, 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")));
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.